# Logo Size Issues; Figma to HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, export, figma

I am design a landing page with figma and it looks good but I am having problems with my images specially with my logo. So figma gives me a specific width and height for my logo and when I write those specifications on my code the logo looks smaller. So there are 2 questions here:

1. when I export my logo from figma should i do it at 1x, 2x or 3x? (working on a regular website)
   2.Does figma use pix or point?

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figma uses pixels. 
1x will render original width and height, for example 100 x 100 
2x will multiply your original size x2 and you will get 200 x 200
3x will multiply your original size x2 and you will get 300 x 300

So those multiply values shouldn't be the case.

To identify your problem I would suggest you to check file info and see what width & height values you see there and if they match values from your design then everything is good with rendering and problem probably is the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are you referring to the figma file info?

Comment: No, I mean just try to export/save logo on your device and see in properties if resolution is the same

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to work with SVGs so you use vector graphics and export as SVG. This will scale infinitely and is very light on size.

If however you don't have vector graphics, but bitmaps, then you need to export either as PNG when using transparency or JPEG when no transparency. Further more you need to export all bitmap images (PNG, JPEG) to 1x, 2x, and 3x.

In your code don't use `<img width="300" srcset="...">` because you let the browser resize the image and you're basically using a bigger image than needed. Instead you should leave the images as they are exported without setting a width/height, ie: `<img srcset="image.jpg 1x, image@2x.jpg 2x, image@3x.jpg 3x">`.

2x and 3x is needed because if the OS is on more than 100% scaling, for example my laptop is at 125%, people will see your 2x images and they will look sharp.

On a side note I recommend giving Desech Studio a try since it imports Figma for you and then you can export to React, Angular, Vue or simple HTML/CSS